# Oracle SQL - Transposing columns as rows while keeping one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table (it is really a view that is derived from complicate logic):

```
|    TYPE | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELDNEEDSTOSTAYASCOLUMN |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------------------------|
|     bad |      1 |      1 |      1 |                     1000 |
| neutral |      2 |      2 |      2 |                     1000 |
|    good |      3 |      3 |      3 |                     1000 |
```

I need to pivot it to the below. Take all the columns and move them as thr rows, but I need to keep the last column.

```
|   FIELD | BAD    | NEUTRAL| GOOD   | FIELDNEEDSTOSTAYASCOLUMN |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------------------------|
| FIELD1  |      1 |      1 |      1 |                     1000 |
| FIELD2  |      2 |      2 |      2 |                     1000 |
| FIELD3  |      3 |      3 |      3 |                     1000 |
```

I have tried using ORacl'es PIVOT and UNPIVOT but have been unable to create this.

This is a fiddle of the sql:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fb63/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  field, bad, neutral, good, fieldneedstostayascolumn
from    mytable
unpivot (val for (field, ord) in (field1 as ('FIELD1', 1), field2 as ('FIELD2', 2),
                                  field3 as ('FIELD3', 3)))
pivot   (min(val) for type in ('bad' as bad, 'neutral' as neutral, 'good' as good))
order   by ord
;



FIELD   BAD NEUTRAL GOOD FIELDNEEDSTOSTAYASCOLUMN
------ ---- ------- ---- ------------------------
FIELD1    1       2    3                     1000
FIELD2    1       2    3                     1000
FIELD3    1       2    3                     1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT
   PROPERTY AS FIELD,
   TYPE,

   VALUE as VAL,
            FIELDNEEDSTOSTAYASCOLUMN
FROM
   MYTABLE
UNPIVOT
EXCLUDE NULLS
(
   VALUE
   FOR
      PROPERTY
   IN
   (
      FIELD1,
      FIELD2,
     FIELD3
   )
))
SELECT * FROM T1
PIVOT
(
   max(VAL)
   FOR
      (TYPE)
   IN
      ('bad','neutral','good')
)
order by FIELD;
```

By the way, your results are not right.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fb63/30/0